# Mutilated string sorting

Tags: string, sorting

I suppose this is a bit of a CS question rather than a "programming" question, but it came up because of the program I'm trying to write, so...

Suppose I have a list of strings, and I sort them in ASCII order. Suppose I now replace every "A" with a "Z". Is the list still in sorted order?

The answer is clearly "no". For example, if our sorted list initially reads

- Andy
- Beth
- Charley

then after the mutilation, it will read

- Zndy
- Beth
- Charley

This is clearly wrong; Zndy should be at the end, not the beginning.

---

Now let me change the process slightly. Suppose instead of replacing "A" with "Z", we replace it with "AZ". Is the list still sorted *now??*

Well, taking our original example, it becomes

- AZndy
- Beth
- Charley

...which *is* still correctly sorted.

At this point I am unable to prove that this always succeeds *or* find an example for which it fails. Can anybody resolve this question one way or the other for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true.

In a sorted list, each row has an attribute which is the length of the common prefix with the next row.

Any changes to a row after this common prefix length are not significant in sorting and maintain the sorted order.

Answer (score 1):

- The question of whether an entire *list* remains sorted after mutilation can be reduced to the question of whether an arbitrary *pair* of strings remains sorted. The list case should then follow by induction. (*I think!*)
- Given any pair of strings, they share a (possibly empty) prefix of identical characters. The next character [or lack thereof] is the "active character" that defines the relative ordering of the two.
- If the common prefix doesn't contain "A", mutilation will not change it.
- If the common prefix does contain "A", mutilation will change both prefixes identically, so they remain identical.
- If one string ends immediately after the common prefix, whatever happens to the other string cannot affect the relative ordering.
- If the active character in one string is "A", it cannot be "A" in the other string. (Otherwise it wouldn't be the active character, it would be in the shared prefix.) Appending a "Z" after the active character cannot affect the relative ordering.

That, I think, constitutes a complete proof...

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing your proof considering the following:

1. Given: list of strings is in order (i.e. a[i] < a[i+1] )
2. Assert: If you replace A with AZ is the list still in order

   consider each string before to be  .... [A] .....
   after each string will be          .... [AZ] ....

(where each string may or may not have an "A" in it

```
You only need to consider strings that had  .....Axxxxxx
that now have                               .....AZxxxxx
```

Rest of proof left as an exercise for questioner